# Android Studio 2.1 Lag

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

My current PC build is 16GB DDR3 RAM, 250GB SSD and an 2.9Ghz i7 processor. Yet this still since I have upgraded to Android Studio 2.1 my whole computer and Android Studio lags. In the past I have seen cases where Android Studio would need up to 2GB of RAM for both it and Java but now it's limited itself to below a gig for each main process. I literally made all of these modifications to the vm options yet still no improvements have been noticed. Builds are still taking 2 minutes. These are the current settings in my .vmptions file. Am I setting a value too high?

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```